# Order of initialisation

Tags: vb.net

I'm playing with the following:

```
Public MustInherit Class TempTable
    Public Sub New()
        For Each f As FieldInfo In Me.GetType().GetFields
            Dim l As TypedLeaf = CType(f.GetValue(Me), TypedLeaf)
            Console.WriteLine(l.Name)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class JMTempTable
    Inherits TempTable

    Public KeyIndex As New TypedLeaf(Me, "KeyIndex", OQL.Type.AUTONUMBER)
    Public Debit As New TypedLeaf(Me, "Debit", OQL.Type.DECIMAL(16, 2))

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

but getting Nothing for the values retrieved.  The reason seems to be that the derived class' fields do not get initialised until *after* the base class' constructor is called... to further complicate matters, if I were to do:

```
Public Class JMTempTable
    Inherits TempTable

    Public KeyIndex As TypedLeaf
    Public Debit As TypedLeaf

    Public Sub New()
        KeyIndex = New TypedLeaf(Me, "KeyIndex", OQL.Type.AUTONUMBER)
        Debit = New TypedLeaf(Me, "Debit", OQL.Type.DECIMAL(16, 2))

        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The compiler will complain that the base class constructor must be called in the first line of the derived class' constructor...

Is there a way I can delay the base class constructor from running until after the derived class' fields have been initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way (perhaps *the* way) to do it:

```
Public MustInherit Class TempTable
    Public Sub New()
        Initialize()
        For Each f As FieldInfo In Me.GetType().GetFields
            Dim l As TypedLeaf = CType(f.GetValue(Me), TypedLeaf)
            Console.WriteLine(l.Name)
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub Initialize()
End Class

Public Class JMTempTable
    Inherits TempTable

    Public KeyIndex As TypedLeaf()
    Public Debit As TypedLeaf()

    Public Sub New() ' Optional block. You don't have to explicitly define a default constructor.
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Initialize()
        KeyIndex = New TypedLeaf(Me, "KeyIndex", OQL.Type.AUTONUMBER)
        Debit = New TypedLeaf(Me, "Debit", OQL.Type.DECIMAL(16, 2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The abstract `Initialize()` method forces inheritors to have a method called `Initialize()`. This method is implicitly called when you call `MyBase.New()`. That means you can now move your initialization logic out of the constructor and into the `Initialize()` method to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Some explanation might be in order.

Answer (score 1):

This is well known behavior in managed languages in general.  Surprisingly I can't find it explicitly mentioned in the VB.NET Language Specification so I'll have to wing it by explaining it myself.

The CLI has direct support for field initializers but they are not strong enough to support your fields.  They can only store simple data, think value types.  Initializing a reference type, like your TypedLeaf class requires executing code.  And code cannot be stored in a field initializer, it can only appear inside of a method.

So the VB.NET compiler works around that restriction by *moving* your field initialization expression to the next logical place, the class constructor.  This is entirely automatic, it actually *rewrites* your constructor, in case you provide one yourself, injecting the *new* operator calls as needed.

Now there's a choice, it could move those calls *before* or *after* the base class constructor call.  You already know the choice that was made, it happens *after*.  With the justification that a field initializer should not be able to observe members of the base class that are not yet initialized.  Your attempt at a workaround is actually pretty heroic compiler writing skills, it actually *checks* that the base constructor is called first.

Unfortunately you found a case where you are actually happier if it happened before the base constructor call.  That's justifiable but unfortunately not permitted, the language designers put their foot down and declared "we only support **one** way to do this".  Fair call, such basics need to be predictable.

The workaround is simple.  Just put a Protected method in your base class, say "Initialize", and move the code you now have in the constructor to that method.  In the derived class constructor just call that method.  The constructor rewriting ensures that the base constructor call is first and the field initializer code is second, making the method call third.  Minus 33.3 points for having to remember to make that call so add the code to throw an InvalidOperationException when you see Nothing.

Comment: the workaround you suggest is what StevenDotNet provided but you get a point for your carefully thought-out analysis.  I would give you two points if I could for also suggesting the exception throwing (though I still need to think about how that would be done)

Comment: Why don't you promise a point to Steven?  He posted the answer you liked.  I already have a quarter of a million of them, I only care about accurate answers, not popular ones.

Comment: Hans, he did get my point and his reply is marked as the answer because  it answers the question in a practical way.  but you get a point too for the analysis

Comment: Incidentally, this behavior makes it possible for a derived-class field initializers to use a constructor parameters (especially nice with things like arrays whose size will never change after construction), if the derived-class constructor passes them to a base-class constructor which then uses them to initialize a base-class field.  IMHO, it's much nicer for a fixed-size collection to be able to write declare an array via `Dim ItemData(Size-1)` than to have to declare it as `Dim ItemData()` and then then in the constructor `Redim ItemData(Size-1)`.

Comment: Of course, better yet would be to have a facility for constructor-parameter-initialized fields and pseudo-fields (a pseudo-field would only be usable in field initializers); parameter-initialized fields and pseudo-fields would require that every constructor for the class either include a parameter with the proper name and type, or else chain to one that does).